# Gwibber and OAuthcalypse

Tags: 10.04, package-management, gwibber

My Gwibber app in 10.04 seems to have fallen victim to the OAuthcalypse. I understand that the latest version of Gwibber has this corrected. What is the easiest way to install a version of Gwibber that will work once again with twitter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## UPDATE

The gwibber version with fixed Twitter OAuth is now in `lucid-updates` Running your update manager via either: System -> Administration -> Update Manager , (or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`) should trigger the update process.

---

The easiest way to grab the latest version of Gwibber is to add the `ubuntu-desktop` PPA (which includes the latest updates for desktop software, including Gwibber)

From command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you don't want the whole `ubuntu-desktop` ppa (which you may not - though it can be quite helpful to avoid issues of this nature in the future) you can simply add the Gwibber Daily PPA which will only provide the updates for Gwibber

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the upgrade you will need to restart Gwibber:

```
gwibber-service restart
```

If that method does not work open the Gwibber interface then choose `Gwibber`->`Quit` and Launch it again either from the Message Indicator Applet or via `Applications`->`Internet`->`Gwibber Social Client`

Once Gwibber has restarted you will need to authenticate your Twitter account. Open the client and navigate to `Edit`->`Accounts` then click **Authorize** on your Twitter account in order to complete the process.

The Oauthcalypse caught me off guard too - even though I was watching the [Countdown to OAuthcalypse](http://countdowntooauth.com) I failed to relate that to Gwibber

Answer (score 0):

Add the Ubuntu Desktop PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
```

and update

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade\
```

then restart Gwibber

```
gwibber-service restart
```

[Source: [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/twitters-oauthpocalypse-today-upgrade.html)]

Comment: I post immediately after some else again. This happened earlier today too!